# I really do not know about file extension .data

Tags: python, path

I have code where the path is this:

```
tr_path = "Folds_Raw/"+fold+"/Train/*.data"
```

I suppose it takes all the files from the path. I putted ".csv" file, ".npy" file, ".txt" file, ".xlsx" file but it does not take any of it. Let me first put my directory  screen shot:

[image: Directory]

Now when I debug the line code here `tr_paths = glob.glob(tr_path, recursive=True)`. It shows empty [ ] list. I am confused what actually this lines of code is doing?

Comment: It's an empty list because there are no `*.data` files in the `Train` folder as tje screenshot clearly shows.

Comment: How I should convert file into .data format

Comment: I've never heard of the `.data` file format, so have no idea how to convert other formats to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only take the files that end with the extension ".data"

You should change:

```
tr_path = "Folds_Raw/"+fold+"/Train/*.data"
```

With:

```
tr_path = "Folds_Raw/"+fold+"/Train/*.*"
```

And it will take all files.

Comment: Thank you for how the prompt response, then how we shod convert files into ".data" format.

Comment: please Pascal mark up my question,  so will get opportunities to upload more questions in future. Thank you

Comment: @martineau please mark up my question,  so will get opportunities to upload more questions in future. Thank you